# How to mock WiFi connection in JUNIT?

Tags: android, junit, mocking, wifi

Using Android and testing on the device, I use this to check, if WiFI is connected:

```
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) MyApplication.getMyApplication().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    return info.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Works well. Is there a way to mock this for JUnit?

Thanx in advance,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can mock this functionality if you move the code into your own WifiServiceClass and let you application depend on the interface:

```
public class MyClassThatRequiresWifi {
    private IWifiService wifiService;
    public MyClassThatRequiresWifi(IWifiService wifiService) {
        this.wifiService = wifiService;
    }

    public void someMethodThatNeedsWifi() {
        if (this.wifiService.isConnectedOrConnecting())
            ...
    }
}

public IWifiService {
    boolean isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

public WifiService implements IWifiService {
    boolean isConnectedOrConnecting() {..}
}
```

Comment: but wouldn't that mean to introduce a so far unneeded class only for testing purposes? On a broader view, that doesn't seem to be right?

Comment: I agree that you have to write an extra class and an extra interface. this is by far much easier than mocking android-s native ConnectivityManager. The Service class is as "(un-)necessary" as seperating an app into gui-, business- and database-layer. I dont think that there is an easier way to mock wifi.